# Add vector as row to matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a vector and a matrix (Array{T,1} and Array{T,2}) in my Julia code and I would like to append them such that the vector becomes a new row in the matrix (should be first row). I've tried several methods (`cat`, etc.) but keep getting errors which I believe are related to the different shape of the data. See the example below.

```
julia> v = Vector([1, 2, 3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> m = Matrix([4 5 6; 7 8 9])
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5  6
 7  8  9

julia> cat(v,m,dims=(1,2))
5×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  0  0  0
 2  0  0  0
 3  0  0  0
 0  4  5  6
 0  7  8  9
```

What I actually want is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I realize that I can get this to work with `transpose(v)` but I was hoping to avoid extra calls.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible (Julia is strict here and treats a normal vector as a column vector). Note that `transpose` is efficient as it does not allocate a new vector.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the answer is to just use `transpose`. I didn't realize it was not creating a new vector.

Comment: Also simply `'` should be good enough in most cases (it is adjoint operation, but if you do not work with complex numbers it should be OK to use and is shorter).

Comment: There's no need to use `Vector` and `Matrix` constructors. `[1,2,3]` is already a vector, and likewise for `m`. The constructor calls are completely redundant, and at worst just do extra work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can change the construction of v to a 1 x 3 array, you can avoid the transpose:

```
julia> v = [1 2 3]
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3

julia> m = [4 5 6; 7 8 9]
2×3 Array{Int64,2}:
4  5  6
7  8  9

julia> vcat(v, m)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

I think that just doing the transpose

```
julia> v2 = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
1
2
3

julia> vcat(v2', m)
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

is almost as efficient though.

Comment: Thanks. However, I was just using the simple example for the question. In the actual code I don't have this option.